# Uneven the component foot after Reflow

Tags: pcb, components, soldering

I have a PCB on the line as shown in the picture, the position of the components is channeled as shown.
By standards this is still acceptable, but I would like to improve the situation.
Please give me advice on how to make the two poles equal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you work for the company doing the PCB assembly? If not, maybe you can ask the company for a recommendation. Some PCB assembly companies have internal expertise in the assembly process.

Comment: The PCB was probably dirty (oil) which prevent the solder to properly wet the pad.

Comment: I think the stencil is ok, but the amount of paste is too much. How about other components? Please show them as well. Because you use a stencil; how is the paste put on the pcb? By hand? You could try a thinner stencil or compensate by making the openings smaller. Although its not the best solution. What kind of paste is used? T3/T4/T5?

Comment: NB: I overlooked the mechanical wear on the stencil, so probably not by hand. But what’s noticeable are the shiny parts; there the stencil maybe makes more contact with the paste scrubber. And the mentioned component does less. Is it possible the pcb is somehow oneven? Like because of the amount of soldermask/varnish?

Comment: @RemyHx We made it by P&P machine, stencil is 4 mils and SAC 305 is what we used.

Comment: Is it possible that the silk screen or solder mask is becoming too thick? Notice that some of the well worn areas on the stencil line up with some silk screen lines.  (Especially noticeable is the worn stencil area running along the silk screen text).  If the stencil is lifted slightly near a pad there can be excess solder paste deposited or pushed under the stencil edge. In areas where there is copper, solder mask, and silk screen the height build up can be even higher. This theory might be testable by asking your PCB vendor for a few samples with no silk screen or with a thinner solder mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure. But it looks like the stencil aperture is unbalanced. Maybe if you make dimension A = dimension B it will work better?

[image]

Comment: Different hole sizes wouldn't affect much as the solder flows into liquid when reflowing it.

Comment: @Damien that is my thinking as well. But it does seem odd to have unbalanced apertures. Anyway, do you have a theory about what is causing it?

Comment: oil on the pad, pcb not cleaned before reflow.